# Can I freely roam on a government owned property, like a police station or a State Bank without permission from anyone?

Tags: property, trespass, government

I wanted to know if the law allows us to freely move or trespass in a government owned property, especially like a police station or State Bank. I know that different countries will have different laws within their own state, but what would a general law say, which most of the countries adhere to?

Comment: If it is trespass, you are not supposed to be there. Plenty of government offices require appropriate ID to be there, including army bases for example.

Comment: I mean which government locations or areas are categorized sensitive and no local can pass from there without proper credentials and permissions, and what doesn't require any? Is there any list, or it depends on country by country basis? If it does, then what law holds in the USA?

Comment: So many downvotes. It was just a simple question. Discouraging.

Answer (score 4):

Owners of property establish rules of trespass.

This applies when the government owns the land just as it does for private property owners.  Being a citizen of a country does not give you ownership rights on government land.  The government is question can apply multiple rules to multiple pieces of property such as:

- Park use only during certain hours of the day
- No unauthorized access
- Access only for certain uses, such as no camping allowed

Certainly no one thinks that military bases, prisons, etc. should have unrestricted access by the public.  In general, if you're not allowed to be there the government will put up barriers, gates, lock doors, etc., or place signage to indicate limits.  Really not all that different from private property.

Comment: So basically, if I want to trespass on any government property, I have to know the rules beforehand. Is there a list which defines these rules within the Constitution of USA, and is it accessible for a common citizen to read?

Comment: @RameezUlHaq no, there is no list defining these rules in the Constitution. You are likely to find them in either statutes or administrative policies of government agencies. For example, your local municipal code and/or school board policies are likely to define when and how citizens are permitted to visit local public school buildings. Rules for citizens entering the Pentagon are going to be a combination of Federal statutes along with current military policies/standing orders/etc.

Comment: I don't have any strong prior information about government laws and how do they work. But I heard from some lawyers that the US constitution allows the locals to visit any government building or property freely (unless it is explicitly mentioned by the government itself that it is prohibited to enter such and such government properties without appropriate credentials/permissions). And the local policies established by those people (municipals) who are managing these government properties don't undo our right to visit them since it is backed by the constitution itself. Is that true?

Comment: @RameezUlHaq  The 1st Amendment stipulates:  "Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press; or the right of the people peaceably to assemble, and to petition the Government for a redress of grievances.”  There is nothing in the Constitution about access to government buildings, though the 1st Amendment may be interpreted to allow users to assemble and speak on government property in some circumstances.

Comment: Makes sense. But I don't understand why all the downvotes, did I ask an extremely awful question.